# eepic package fails compiling

Tags: compiling

I have some problems with `eepic` package.

When I use the `eepic` package almost everything works fine, except circles. The circles were shown half (circle lines and filled circles).
When I add the `eepic` package a large part of the lines are lost arrows are lost, circles are lost.
Only text doesn't change. When I load both packages, the order of loading the packages changed the way the compiler works (or does not work).

I have made a copy from: [webpage with samples](http://www.ursoswald.ch/LaTeXGraphics/picture/picture.html#GoossensL)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[]{epic,eepic}
    \setlength{\unitlength}{1mm}
    \begin{picture}(60,30)
      \put(0,29){$A$} \put(5,30){\line(1,0){20}} 
      \put(28,30){\circle*{2}} 
      \put(28,30){\vector(0,-1){10}}
      \put(30,29){Masse f\"allt aus}
      \put(30,25){Ruhelage}
      \put(0, 9){$B$} 
      \put(5,10){\line(1,0){20}}
      \put(0,5){\line(1,0){40}}
      \multiput(1,5)(1,0){40}{\line(-2,-5){2}}
      \put(15,10){\line(0,1){20}} \put(16,19){$h$}
    \end{picture}
\end{document}
```

and do this with my own laptop and with sharelatex. both give the same result see figure [image: figure]

What goes wrong and what do I have to do?

Comment: Exactly which code are you using? Instead of refering som some webpage, it might be an idea to post something that others can copy and test on their own PCs. That makes it a lot more likely that you get help. Besides, isn;t the cool kids using `tikz` these days? It can do a *lot* more.

Comment: i have add one of the samples

Comment: That is a sniplet, please provide one that include preamble etc. Basically it should be ready to test for others without having to add anything. Often the process of preparing such a minimal *document* ends up narrowing down the error.

Answer (score 2):

You can compile your code by replacing `\usepackage[]{epic,eepic}` by `\usepackage{pict2e}`. This new package uses the same syntax in this case.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pict2e}
\setlength{\unitlength}{1mm}
\begin{document}
\begin{picture}(60,30)
\put(0,29){$A$} \put(5,30){\line(1,0){20}} 
\put(28,30){\circle*{2}} 
\put(28,30){\vector(0,-1){10}}
\put(30,29){Masse f\"allt aus}
\put(30,25){Ruhelage}
\put(0, 9){$B$} 
\put(5,10){\line(1,0){20}}
\put(0,5){\line(1,0){40}}
\multiput(1,5)(1,0){40}{\line(-2,-5){2}}
\put(15,10){\line(0,1){20}} \put(16,19){$h$}
\end{picture}
\end{document}
```

[image]